# Drawing a flow chart

Tags: flow-charts, mindmaps

I tried the code to get this particular flow chart but the flow chart is going out of the page. This code is not complete also for complete flow chart. Also can you suggest how can it be plotted in mindmaps?

[image: flowchart][image: accordingtothecode]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
    
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, node distance=2cm, text width=16em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, 
    fill=red!30]
    
    \tikzstyle{bluee} = [rectangle, draw, node distance=2cm, text width=12em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, 
    fill=blue!30]
    
    \tikzstyle{blks} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, node distance=1.5cm, text width=6em,  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick]
    
    
    \tikzstyle{big} = [rectangle, draw, inner sep=0.5cm, thick]
    
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex',thick]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}\centering
        \node [block](exe) {\textbf{Thesis}};
        \node [blks, below=of exe] (fin) {\textbf{Chapter 3}};
        \node [blks, right=of fin] (prod) {\textbf{Chapter 4}};
        \node [blks, left=of fin] (resch) {\textbf{Chapter 2}};
        \node [blks,left=of resch] (mgm) {\textbf{Chapter 1\\
                Introduction}};
        \node [blks,below left= of mgm] (b) {\textbf{b}};
            \node [blks,below = of mgm] (c) {\textbf{c}};
            \node [blks,below right = of mgm] (d) {\textbf{Black hole Thermodynamics}};
        
        \path [line] (exe)-|(mgm);
        \path [line] (exe)--(fin);
        \path [line] (exe)--(prod);
        \path [line] (exe)--(resch);
        \path [line] (mgm) -- (b);
        \path [line] (mgm) -- (c);
        \path [line] (mgm) -- (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Thanks for the manual drawing. Would be nice, if you could insert, what your code produces, too. // For mindmaps, as incldued in tikz, kindly visit here: https://tikz.dev/library-mindmaps

Comment: The flow chart is getting out of the paper means it gets cut from the paper. I have uploaded the picture.

Comment: Thank you. From inspecting your code, it looks like you built-in a lot of trouble. If you want to continue, I suggesst to use this class while you develop the drawing: `\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}` ... it will resize as needed.

Comment: TikZ can't magically make a drawing fit your page. Besides changing the page size just for this diagram, you might be able to change the whole direction of the graph (i.e. it grows to the right instead of down) or rotate it (so that it's a landscape page). Does it really need to be a mindmap? They waste even more space and in my opinion are more distracting than helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, let's have a look. The first thing I tried, was working with your code ... with some success.

#### Working with your code

To get rid of the cut-off problem during developing the drawing, use `\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}`, which will expand as needed and will put one "page" per `tikzpicture`.

No idea, where you've got `\tikzstyle{block} = [re...` from. To define styles just use, while watching the `,` at the end, e.g.:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={draw, node distance=2cm, text width=16em, text centered,
                  minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, fill=red!30},
    bluee/.style={draw, node distance=2cm, text width=12em,text centered,
                  minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    blks/.style={ draw, fill=white, node distance=1.5cm, text width=6em,
                  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick},
    big/.style={draw, inner sep=0.5cm, thick},
    line/.style={draw, -latex',thick}
    ]%\centering
    
    \node [block]               (exe)   {\textbf{Thesis}};
...
```

As you can see, I deleted irrelevant statements. Also, there is some redundancy, which one would remove sooner than later. But that's not the point here.

Inserting a dummy node `(DMY)` and readjusting as needed gives a little bit of what you want, with some flaw. You'll probably want to adopt what I describe further down below (full code at the end). Result:

[image: result 1]

#### A different design strategy

You don't have to put the top box as the first node. Looking at your sketch suggests something different:

[image: sketch]

Assuming this design won't change too much, it seems to be more obvious to put the lower block first (ch2-ch5). Wrt "bent" connectors you may want to have some "fixed" coordinates A, B etc., at least as a conceptual idea.

It's also a good idea to draw the structure first and care about exact appearance later (widths, fonts, colors ...).

By mixing some absolute postions (coordinates) with some relative positioning, you'll be flexible enough, later, when more details flow in.

#### Building the structure first

[image: result 2]

So, my code now follows a series of `\node ... \draw ...` blocks, augmented with some comments (as tomorrow I'll have forgotten all my beautiful concepts ...).

Let's run through important points to understand my suggested code.

Because arrows will be used a lot, and the standard is somewhat hard to see, all `>` in `[->]` are replaced by `[-{Stealth}]`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <<< new
...
 % ~~~ alternative ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Stealth}
    ]
```

Absolute coordinates: I intended to use many of them, while it turned out, that just the first one is relevant, put arbitrarily as: `\coordinate (A) (0,0);`.

Now the lower block can be placed with relative positioning like:

```
    % ~~~ lower block of blocks ~~~~~~~~
    \node[below=of A]   (c4) {Chapter 4};
    \node[right=of c4]  (c5) {Chapter 5};
...
```

Which makes it also easy to connect all those nodes, like:

```
    % ~~~ connecting lower blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c2);
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c3);
...
```

The connectors to the conclusion may be a bit tricky for a beginner in tikz:

```
    \draw[->] (e) |- +(0,-.7) -| (con);
    \draw[->] (f) |- +(0,-.65) -|(con);
    \draw[->] (g) -- (con);
    \draw[->] (h) |- +(0,-.65) -|(con);
```

Instead of a direct connection `(e) -- (con);` there now is an intermediate coordinate, which decodes as:

- take coordinates of (e)
- add (0,-0.65) to (e) AND forget (`+`)
- continue drawing to (con)
- put some vertical lines as nedded/indicated

Now the rest becomes easier:

- put the thesis node somewhere up `\node at (-2,5) (ths) {Thesis};` (absolute position)
- put Chapter 1 below left AND shift it a little more  `\node[below left=of ths,xshift=-2cm] (c1)   {Chapter 1};`
- repeat, what I described, for the rest

#### Outlook

Once you are happy (enough) with the structure, introduce content (e.g. replace "a") and formatting, step-by-step.

The smaller your steps, the easier you can react on smashed designs, as it was already ok the moment before, until you ... . Should be easier to spot and to correct.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,arrows,calc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% <<< new


\begin{document}  

 % ~~~ original, with some rework, unfinished ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    block/.style={draw, node distance=2cm, text width=16em, text centered,
                  minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, fill=red!30},
    bluee/.style={draw, node distance=2cm, text width=12em,text centered,
                  minimum height=4em, thick,draw=black, fill=blue!30},
    blks/.style={ draw, fill=white, node distance=1.5cm, text width=6em,
                  text centered, minimum height=4em, thick},
    big/.style={draw, inner sep=0.5cm, thick},
    line/.style={draw, -latex',thick}
    ]%\centering
    
    \node [block]               (exe)   {\textbf{Thesis}};
    \node [blks, below=of exe]  (fin)   {\textbf{Chapter 3}};
    \node [blks, right=of fin]  (prod)  {\textbf{Chapter 4}};
    \node [blks, left=of fin]   (resch) {\textbf{Chapter 2}};
    \node [blks,left=of resch]  (mgm)   {\textbf{Chapter 1\\Introduction}};
    \node [below=of mgm]        (DMY)   {}; % an invisible dummy node
    % adjusting the nodes for DMY
    \node [blks,below = of DMY] (c) {\textbf{c}};
    \node [blks,left=of c]      (b) {\textbf{b}};
    \node [blks,right=of c]     (d) {\textbf{Black hole Thermodynamics}};
        
    \path [line] (exe)-|(mgm);
    \path [line] (exe)--(fin);
    \path [line] (exe)--(prod);
    \path [line] (exe)--(resch);
    \path [line] (mgm) -- (DMY);% new
    % wrt DMY node
    \path [line] (DMY) -| (b);
    \path [line] (DMY) -- (c);
    \path [line] (DMY) -| (d);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 
 % ~~~ alternative ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
        >={Stealth}
    ]
    % ~~~ coordinates will semi-fix the blocks and help guiding the conenctions
    \coordinate (A) (0,0);
    %\coordinate (B) (0,-10);
    
    % ~~~ lower block of blocks ~~~~~~~~
    \node[below=of A]   (c4) {Chapter 4};
    \node[right=of c4]  (c5) {Chapter 5};
    \node[left=of c4]   (c3) {Chapter 3};
    \node[left=of c3]   (c2) {Chapter 2};
    %
    \node[below=of c2]  (e)  {e};
    \node[below=of c3]  (f)  {f};
    \node[below=of c4]  (g)  {g};
    \node[below=of c5]  (h)  {h};
    %
    \node[below=of g]   (con){Conclusions};
    
    % ~~~ connecting lower blocks ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c2);
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c3);
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c4);
    \draw[->] (A) -| (c5);
    %
    \draw[->] (c2) -- (e);
    \draw[->] (c3) -- (f);
    \draw[->] (c4) -- (g);
    \draw[->] (c5) -- (h);
    %
    \draw[->] (e) |- +(0,-.7) -| (con);
    \draw[->] (f) |- +(0,-.65) -|(con);
    \draw[->] (g) -- (con);
    \draw[->] (h) |- +(0,-.65) -|(con);
    
    % ~~~ THESIS node ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node at (-2,5) (ths) {Thesis};
    
    % ~~~ Chapter 1 ~~~~
    \node[below left=of ths,xshift=-2cm] (c1)   {Chapter 1};
    \node[below=of c1]       (b)    {b};
    \node[left=of b]         (a)    {a};
    \node[right=of b]        (c)    {c};
    \node[right=of c]        (d)    {d};
    
    % ~~~ connecting thesis and chapter 1 ~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (ths) -| (c1);
    \draw[->] (c1) -- (b);
    \draw[->] (c1) -- +(0,-.7) -| (a);
    \draw[->] (c1) -- +(0,-.7) -| (c);
    \draw[->] (c1) -- +(0,-.7) -| (d);
    
    % ~~~ connecting thesis with lower block ~~~~
    \draw[->] (ths) -- +(0,-2) -| (A);
    
    % ~~~ future work ~~~~~~~
    \node at (6,3) (fut) {Future work};
    
    % ~~~ connecting thesis and future work ~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (ths) -- +(5,0) |- (fut);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```